# Read And Write To Header Message MQ C#

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, mq

I am reading an MQMessage in like so

```
       queue.Get(message, gmo);

        string message1 = message.ReadString(message.MessageLength);
```

I can see there is a `message.UserId on MQMessage`, but that is not enough

I want the users to get additional information in the message header of an MQMessage.

How can I set and then retrieve the following from a header of an MQMessage

```
username 
password
mySpecialID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done like this

```
msg.SetStringProperty("NicksProp", "blahblah");
```

Comment: Now the question is how do I retrieve that property when I do  queue.Get(mqMessage, mqGetNextMsgOpts);

Comment: On the receiving end:

mqMessage.GetStringProperty("NicksProp");

Answer (score 1):

Note: MQ treats message properties as plain text, so if you are sending a password as a message property then EVERYONE can see it.  You will be able to see it via WireShark, and/or in the queue with any tool (MQ Explorer) and/or in the MQ log files.

Comment: it being encypted will be fine no?

Comment: Are you saying that the code will invoke an encryption routine before using SetStringProperty() method?  What encryption are you planning on using?  How will the sender and receiver share the encryption key (or certificate)?